# Will mongodb use 2 indexes in this $or query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Index 1:

```
{
  A: 1
}
```

Index 2:

```
{
  B: 1
}
```

query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        A: { $eq: 100 },
        B: { $eq: 100 },
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Will mongodb use both indexes in this query?

Comment: Have you tried it? We've mentioned checking `explain()` output I'm a number of your recent questions. Should be pretty quick to run the command and see what plans are considered (`rejectedPlans` field) and chosen (`winningPlan`). The `$or documentation page also has details about index usage

Answer (score 0):

according to docs:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

it will use both indexes.